# How to use tokenizer in java with , delimiters?

Tags: java, delimiter, stringtokenizer

I have a sample input file as follows -

> OPCODE R1, R2, R3
>   OPCODE R2, #30

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(scanner.nextLine());
    Instruction instruction = new Instruction();
    instruction.setAddress(PC + PC_increment);
    instruction.setOpcode(st.nextToken());
    if(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        instruction.setDest(st.nextToken());
    }
    if(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String nextToken = st.nextToken();
        if(nextToken.charAt(0)== '#') {
            instruction.setSource_1(nextToken.split("#")[1]);
        } 
        else {
            instruction.setSource_1(nextToken);
        }
    }   
    if(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        instruction.setSource_2(st.nextToken());
    }
}
```

When I am trying to print the token I am getting "R1," and "R2," as the output. However, I am expecting just R1 or R2 as output. Also, I don't want the `#` in the case of second line. How can I do it? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default delimiter for `StringTokenizer` is the space character (space, tab, new-line), **not** the comma `,`. Then the tokens from your first line are: "OPCODE", "R1,", "R2," and "R3".

If you want to split the string on white spaces **and** comma you should use (note the added `,` at the end of the default list of delimiters):

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(scanner.nextLine(), " \t\n\r\f,");
```

Also to remove the leading `#`, you could just do

```
if(nextToken.startWith("#")) {
    instruction.setSource_1(nextToken.substring(1));
}
```

But, if you read the [JDK documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) it is written:

> StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.

Answer (score 0):

StringTokenizer class is deprecated now. It is recommended to use split() method of String class or regex (Regular Expression).

Here in the code the seperation between the tokens is comma(",") So you have to mention that in string tokenizer else default token seperator is "space".So we have to mention as
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(scanner.nextLine(),",");

What ever you mention in inverted commas will act as a splitter between the tokens.

Also you can use subString method to remove "#".